# Prevent unprocessed DOT files from being deleted when using Doxywizard

Tags: documentation, doxygen, diagram, dot, doxygen-wizard

I'm using Doxygen wizard to generate documentation for a big embedded C project. I'm able to generate graphs and class diagrams using Dot and Graphviz. However, I would like to edit some dependency graphs by hand - there's information that is not needed all the time e.g. the graph depth is too much.

I noticed when running Doxywizard that before the diagram files are generated and saved as PNG files, "raw files" for lack of a better word are created that hold the code to generate the graphs using Graphviz. These are DOT files that can be opened in the text editor. These files are deleted once the diagram images are generated.

I was able to access them by stopping the Doxywizard mid-process before they got deleted. Is there any way to prevent these DOT files from being deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen has the possibility to retain the `dot` files. In the doxygen settings file (`Doxyfile`) there is the setting `DOT_CLEANUP` setting this to `DOT_CLEANUP=NO` will retain the files.

From the documentation:

> DOT_CLEANUP
>
> If the DOT_CLEANUP tag is set to YES, doxygen will remove the intermediate files that are used
> to generate the various graphs.
> Note: This setting is not only used for dot files but also for msc temporary files.
> The default value is: YES

See also: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html and more specifically: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_dot_cleanup

And in the doxywizard:

[image]

i.e.

- expert tab
- topics "pane" the last item `dot`
- in the list of possibilities the last item `DOT_CLEANUP`